# Display a header on top tr in a table

Tags: jquery

I have written the Jquery which will convert the result to Pivot which is working as expected. But I need a small help

```js
var array1 = [];

var jsonArray = [{
  "Chapter": "Chemistry",
  "StudentModel": [{
    "StudentName": "Ankit",
    "StudentId": 100,
    "Marks": 23,
    "ResultDate": "01/23/20"
  }, {
    "StudentName": "Ankit",
    "StudentId": 186,
    "Marks": 50,
    "ResultDate": "02/06/20"
  },
  {
    "StudentName": "Anirudh",
    "StudentId": 201,
    "Marks": 50,
    "ResultDate": "02/06/20"
  }
  ]
}, {
  "Chapter": "Physics",
  "StudentModel": [{
    "StudentName": "Rahul",
    "StudentId": 200,
    "Marks": 1.2,
    "ResultDate": "01/23/20"
  }]
}]

$.each(jsonArray, function(index, item) {
  //array.push(item.ChapterHeading);
  $.each(item.StudentModel, function(index, item) {
    var array = [];
    array.push(item.StudentName);
    array.push(item.Marks);
    array.push(item.ResultDate);
    array1.push(array);
  });

});

function getPivotArray(dataArray, rowIndex, colIndex, dataIndex) {
  var result = {},
    ret = [];
  var newCols = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {

    if (!result[dataArray[i][rowIndex]]) {
      result[dataArray[i][rowIndex]] = {};
    }
    result[dataArray[i][rowIndex]][dataArray[i][colIndex]] = dataArray[i][dataIndex];

    //To get column names
    if (newCols.indexOf(dataArray[i][colIndex]) == -1) {
      newCols.push(dataArray[i][colIndex]);
    }
  }

  newCols.sort();
  var item = [];

  //Add Header Row
  item.push('StudentName');
  item.push.apply(item, newCols);
  ret.push(item);

  //Add content 
  for (var key in result) {
    item = [];
    item.push(key);
    for (var i = 0; i < newCols.length; i++) {
      item.push(result[key][newCols[i]] || "N/A");
    }
    ret.push(item);
  }
  return ret;
}

function arrayToHTMLTable(myArray) {
  var result = "<table class='table table-striped'>";
  for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    result += "<tr>";
    for (var j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++) {
      result += "<td>" + myArray[i][j] + "</td>";
    }
    result += "</tr>";
  }
  result += "</table>";

  return result;
}



$(function() {
  var output = getPivotArray(array1, 0, 2, 1);
  //$('#orgTable').html(arrayToHTMLTable(arr));
  $('#pivotTable').html(arrayToHTMLTable(output));

});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pivotTable"></div>
```

On top of a list I would like to display the header like for **Ankit** and **Anirudh** it should be **Chemistry** and for **Rahul** on top it should show **Physics**. Can some one help me so that is should be like

[image]

Comment: That would just be a `<td colspan="4">Chemistry</td>` as the only record in the row

Comment: Yeah but in the loop I need to adjust that I am not getting. I don't want to hard code it

Comment: Also colspan can't be fixed as the date range may vary :)

Comment: I mean, the logic is going to have to be dynamic to know it needs to put the colspan on the td anyways.  Knowing what the value of the colspan should be would also be part of that dynamic nature.

Comment: But the date range is the length of the jsonArray, or?

Comment: Yes in json array it will be

Comment: Is the service that returns this json open for modification?  Because the amount of work you are having to do to massage the data to get it into a form that supports what you want to do, is not small.

Comment: I didn't get you, the JSON will be in the same format I posted. I tried by doing the pivot in c# code but failed to achieve.

Comment: I'm asking if the structure of the returned JSON is open for modification.

Comment: You mean to say changing it?

Comment: You can use Datatables to achieve what you want: https://datatables.net/

Comment: Hi `Danilo` can  I get any specific example as per my requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some trick and able to get it

```js
var headerCols = [];
var firstItem = "";
var array1 = [];
var newCols = [];

var jsonArray = [{
  "Chapter": "Chemistry",
  "StudentModel": [{
    "StudentName": "Ankit",
    "StudentId": 100,
    "Marks": 23,
    "ResultDate": "01/23/20"
  }, {
    "StudentName": "Ankit",
    "StudentId": 186,
    "Marks": 50,
    "ResultDate": "02/06/20"
  }, {
    "StudentName": "Anirudh",
    "StudentId": 201,
    "Marks": 50,
    "ResultDate": "02/06/20"
  }]
}, {
  "Chapter": "Physics",
  "StudentModel": [{
    "StudentName": "Rahul",
    "StudentId": 200,
    "Marks": 1.2,
    "ResultDate": "01/23/20"
  }]
}]

$.each(jsonArray, function(index, chapter) {
  //array.push(item.ChapterHeading);
  $.each(chapter.StudentModel, function(index, item) {
    var array = [];
    if (index === 0) {
      firstItem = item.StudentName;
    }
    var is_last_item = (index == (chapter.StudentModel.length - 1));
    array.push(item.StudentName);
    array.push(item.Marks);
    array.push(item.ResultDate);
    array1.push(array);
    if (is_last_item) {
      array.push(firstItem + "_" + chapter.Chapter);
    }
  });

});

function getPivotArray(dataArray, rowIndex, colIndex, dataIndex, headerCol) {
  var result = {},
    ret = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {

    if (!result[dataArray[i][rowIndex]]) {
      result[dataArray[i][rowIndex]] = {};
    }
    result[dataArray[i][rowIndex]][dataArray[i][colIndex]] = dataArray[i][dataIndex];
    if (dataArray[i][headerCol] !== undefined) {
      headerCols.push(dataArray[i][headerCol]);
    }

    //To get column names
    if (newCols.indexOf(dataArray[i][colIndex]) == -1) {
      newCols.push(dataArray[i][colIndex]);
    }
  }

  newCols.sort();
  var item = [];

  //Add Header Row
  item.push('StudentName');
  item.push.apply(item, newCols);
  ret.push(item);

  //Add content 
  for (var key in result) {
    item = [];
    item.push(key);
    for (var i = 0; i < newCols.length; i++) {
      item.push(result[key][newCols[i]] || "N/A");
    }
    ret.push(item);
  }
  return ret;
}

function arrayToHTMLTable(myArray) {
  var colName = '';
  var position = 0;
  var result = "<table class='table table-striped'>";
  for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    position = i;
    colName = myArray[position][0];
    $.each(headerCols, function(i, header) {
      var splitHeader = header.split("_");
      if (colName !== undefined && splitHeader[0] === colName) {
        result += "<tr style='background-color:#DBF3FA;'><td colspan=" + newCols.length + 1 + ">" + splitHeader[1] + "</td></tr>";
      }
    })
    result += "<tr>";
    for (var j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++) {
      result += "<td>" + myArray[i][j] + "</td>";
    }
    result += "</tr>";
  }
  result += "</table>";

  return result;
}



$(function() {
  var output = getPivotArray(array1, 0, 2, 1, 3);
  //$('#orgTable').html(arrayToHTMLTable(arr));
  $('#pivotTable').html(arrayToHTMLTable(output));

});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pivotTable"></div>
```